# What is the Regex to validate this kind String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have this kind of String ('123','12345678') and i would validate it throw a regex.
I have write this code, but i'm not shure it work.

```
String field = "('123','12345678')";
String regex = "^('\\d{3}','\\d{8}')$";
public void valideField(String field, String regex){
{
    if(!field.matches(regex)){
        System.out.println("Not validated!");
    }

}
```

Is correct regex or not? You have any suggestions or help?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here

Comment: This might help? http://txt2re.com/

Comment: So you want to check if the string is "`('` three digits here `','` eight digits here `')`"?

Comment: You're not sure if it works? Can't you... run it, and find out?

Comment: I want check if the string present in code respect a pattern like ('three number digit','eight number digit'). I think the code is clear

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape parentheses (using backslashes) as they represent capturing groups in regular expressions:

```
String regex = "^\\('\\d{3}','\\d{8}'\\)$";
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to escape the single quotes and parenthesis too with `\\'` and `\\(`

The correct regex would be:

```
String regex = "\\(\\'\\d{3}\\',\\'\\d{8}\\'\\)";
```

Comment: why escape single quote? There is no need to escape single quote in JAVA. Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/1)